# EchMultiselect(TypeError: m.easing[this.easing] is not a function)

Tags: yii

I am using EchMultiselect to create a multiple select.

```
         $this->widget('ext.widgets.EchMultiSelect', 
         array(
        'model' => $modelCtas,
        'dropDownAttribute' => 'CATServiceID',
        'data' => $data,
        'dropDownHtmlOptions' => array(
        'style' => 'width:378px;',
        ),
```

It works fine, but it doesn’t collapse and the close button is not working.
I get the JQuery error TypeError: m.easing[this.easing] is not a function.
What could be the issue.?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you need to make sure:

1) jQuery UI is used in your project.

2) if jQuery UI its include, Then you have an error in jQuery UI version, this ext is tested on Yii 1, so that make sure you are include truth version for jQuery UI if you using Yii2, or upgrade ext if you are in Yii 1 version.

Comment: I am using Yii 1.1.16 and jQuery UI - v1.11.2

Comment: Please, open page source and check theres no jQuery doplucate like inlcude jQuery and jQuery.min ...if no deplucate,  try to put jQuery UI <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js'> and check if its work with this version ...